# Certificated Not Trusted Apps UWP Windows When Install at Another PC/Laptop

Tags: uwp, installation, visual-studio-2017, certificate, react-native-windows

I have a problem regarding UWP Apps ...
I have made a bundle with apps.appx extension through Visual Studio 2017.
I want to install the Apps on a different Laptop / PC, but when I want to install, the certificate is not trusted while on my PC / Laptop it is Trusted.
How do I make a certificate that apps are always trusted even though they are installed on various PCs / Laptops ...?
thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you're sideloading then you will need to trust the certificate manually.
Just double click the certificate file before installation, then take the following steps:

*Install Certificate > Local Machine > Place All certificates in the following store > Browse > **Trusted People** (That isn't a typo).*

Your certificate should then be installed on that PC  and any app updates or further apps developed using the same certificate should install without any issues.

Comment: thanks this works. I was trying all the time Trusted Publishers and it doesnt work. trust people works not sure the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Certificates could be trusted by most of the devices. The key is you need to trust the certificate manually. If you want to trust a certificate on a device the device that haven't installed the certificate before, you need manually add your certificate to different devices. Double click the .cer file that generated with your package, choose local machine and install the certificate under trusted people.